# How to sort result by name?

Tags: php

Code will check directory and makes list of files. Currently result list is not sorted. Would like that result list is sorted alphabetically.

How to sort result list file names alphabetically in result list?

```
<?php
  if ($handle = opendir('.')) {
    while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle))) {
      if ($file != "." && $file != "..") {
        $thelist .= '<li><a href="'.$file.'">'.$file.'</a></li>';
}
    }
    closedir($handle);
  }

?>
<h1>List of CMR`s:</h1>
<ul><?php echo $thelist; ?></ul>
```

Comment: Put all the filenames in an array, and use `sort($array)`.

Comment: you can use `scandir` instead `opendir` it should return items in alphabetical order

Answer (score 0):

use scandir() instead of readdir(). scandir() read and  returns an array of files and directories sorted *alphabetically*.

```
<?php
  $files = scandir('.');
  $thelist = '';
  foreach ($files as $file) {
    if ($file != "." && $file != "..") {
      $thelist .= '<li><a href="'.$file.'">'.$file.'</a></li>';
    }
  }
?>
<h1>List of CMR`s:</h1>
<ul><?php echo $thelist; ?></ul>
```